# 3-class classification with different costs

Tags: r, regression, classification

Consider the following scenario: I have an auto dealership, and I want to decide whether to buy a used car. If it's a good buy, I would make a substantial amount of money of it. If it's a bad buy, I would lose a substantial amount of money. If it's neither ("nop") , I would lose a small amount of money.

Naturally, I start with training and testing sets, and then use a simple 2-class classifier, that aims to predict whether it's a good buy or a bad buy ( I used [gbm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html) ,whose latest version, by the way, now includes also multinomial regression!).

Once I have my classifier, I can look at my testing set, and inspect the cars that the classifier told me to buy. with these cars, I would calculate my expected future earnings:

```
   number of good buys X profit - number of bad buys x loss - number of 'nop' buys x smaller loss.
```

So, if you think about it, I actually shouldn't be trying to classify. I should try and find an area in my features space in which the given criterion is maximized. However, this sound like a combinatorial problem.

So (finally), my question is: what algorithm / method is there that I can use to maximize my cost function?

Thanks a lot!